# IBM MQ (IBMMQDotnetClient) - MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN trying to Get message from queue

Tags: c#, .net-core, ibm-mq

I am using IBMMQDotnetClient 9.2.3 NuGet on .NET (Core) 5, SSL enabled.

There is no problem when I Put messages to queue - it works perfectly.

But when I try to Get messages from queue, sometimes it fails with **CompCode: 2, Reason: 2009** (**MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN**) error.

I say sometimes, because it happens randomly - sometimes everything is fine and I get all messages successfully, other times I only manage to get first few messages and then get this error. When I run it again, it usually gets stuck on the same message it failed last time - until I run old MQ client on .NET Framework, which never fails and gets all remaining messages for me.

Message count in queue is 10 - 20 every day and size of them is 1KB - 150KB, so nothing special here.

So far the issue only occurs in production environment.

In trace files I found another error:

```
System.ArgumentException: Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.
   at System.Buffer.BlockCopy(Array src, Int32 srcOffset, Array dst, Int32 dstOffset, Int32 count)
   at IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.MQProxyQueue.AddMessage(MQTSH tsh, MQASYNC_MESSAGE async)
   at IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.MQProxyQueueManager.AddMessage(MQTSH tsh)
   at IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.MQRcvThread.Run()
```

which is followed by **CompCode: 2 Reason: 2195** and then **CompCode: 2 Reason: 2009**

Here is the code I use:

```
var options = MQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
MqQueue = MqQueueManager.AccessQueue(name, options);

var getMessageOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions();
getMessageOptions.Options += MQC.MQGMO_WAIT + MQC.MQGMO_SYNCPOINT;
getMessageOptions.WaitInterval = 100;
getMessageOptions.MatchOptions = MQC.MQMO_NONE;

var mqMessage = new MQMessage();
MqQueue.Get(mqMessage, getMessageOptions);
```

I've been trying to change configuration, like removing **WaitInterval** and setting **MQC.MQGMO_NO_WAIT** - then I no longer got 2009 error, but each message took 5 or even 10 minutes to get, which is just too long, so it's not an option for me.

I really don't want to get stuck in .NET Framework forever.
Is there any solution / workaround I could use in this situation?

Comment: Can you turn off read ahead - `ALTER QLOCAL(qname) DEFREADA(DISABLED)` - since you seem to be failing in the proxy queue code. That said, whether this makes a difference or not it sounds like you should raise a case with IBM.

Comment: Taking 5 minutes to get one message is too long a time. Generally it takes few milli seconds to get a message, depending where application and queue manager are located. Would it possible to show more of your code? Agree with @MoragHughson regarding raising case with IBM.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an APAR opened for this issue and this is specific to .NET Core. You can try by decreasing the heartbeat interval. The data is stuck in the socket, so until the next data arrives on the socket the data isn't read.